# The command 'which cd' prints nothing in 12.04

Tags: command-line, bash

The command `which cd` prints nothing. Same for `whatis cd` and `whereis cd`. How can I find out if cd is an alias, function, or bash built-in? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In bash, `which` is an external utility. It only finds external commands: it does not know about aliases, builtins or functions. The same goes for `whatis` and `whereis`.

Forget `which` and use `type` instead.

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Builtins don't have a man page of their own (unless they also exist as an external utility, but then you get the documentation of the external utility, which may support different options). They are documented in the bash manual.

See also [How to use `which` on an aliased command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command) and [My `which` command may be wrong (sometimes)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47363/my-which-command-may-be-wrong-sometimes)

Comment: I like `type -a` too -- it shows *all* executables/alias/function -- example `type -a [`

Comment: `type` with its various options is definitely more reliable. `which` shows tremendous variations in power from distro to distro (cf. red hat vs debian).

Answer (score 0):

`man bash` will tell you that. Move to the end and then search for **BASH BUILTIN COMMANDS**. You can read on from there.

Answer (score 0):

To list all bash aliases:

```
alias
```

To list all defined function names:

```
typeset -F
```

To see the list of bash builtins, check the bash manpage.

You can probably hack together a single script to grep through the output of each command above.